# Eclipse e4 - Logger Injection

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp, code-injection, e4

As far as I have understood reading online articles, the embedded data-logger in Eclipse should be best deal especially if you're implementing an RCP app. (Confirm?)

Anyway I'm struggling using it.

The first issue I have faced is a problem with Injection:

```
import org.eclipse.e4.core.services.Logger;

@Inject
private Logger logger;
```

In an MPart it produces a null variable.

Comment: Have you added `org.eclipse.e4.core.services` to the plug-in deps?

Comment: Which version of Eclipse? In Eclipse 4.4 the Logger is in the `org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log` package. But you should get a 'cannot find instance of logger' injection error if an instance of the class cannot be found. Don't forget that field injection is done after construction, so you can't use this field in the constructor.

Comment: I'm using Eclipse Luna 4.4 and the declaration is set after construction

Comment: Anyway now it works! Probably i screwed up with dependencies. Is it better to use the embedded Logger or log4j? What do you think?

Comment: If you use third-party libraries that use some other well-known loggers, log4j allows you to redirect their output to your log.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems when I tried to use a Logger inside a handler in a e4  plugin and starting the plugin inside Eclipse Version: 2023-12 (4.30.0).

The dependency injection was not able to resolve the logger at this point .

As a workaround I did inject the eclipse context and resolved the logger from there:

```java
import org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.IEclipseContext;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.di.annotations.Execute;
import org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log.Logger;
import org.eclipse.e4.ui.services.IServiceConstants;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class SomeHandler {

    @Inject
    IEclipseContext context;

    @Execute
    public void execute(@Named(IServiceConstants.ACTIVE_SHELL) Shell s) {

        Logger logger = context.get(Logger.class);
        logger.info("Info log entry - visible in Error log view");

        // further stuff
    }
```

But there are some caveats:

- `org.eclipse.e4.core.services.log.Logger` has restricted api access
- when using the workaround, the plugin inside the log is always
  `org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench` and not your own (means not like in activator loggers  - which was e3 the way to access the logger)

Currently I did not found a better/quicker way.
And it was the only way mentioned in the (now outdated) [wiki description](https://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/Doc/Logging#Java)